# DAO layer takes only some parameters for creating object

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, crud, dao

I'm trying to add person to admin person that inheretence person with DAO layer but it only takes some parameters .
Person:

```
public class Person {

    protected String name;
    protected String username;
    protected String password;


    public Person() {

        this.name = "";
        this.username = "";
        this.password = "";
        }

    public Osoba( String name, String username, String password) {

        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

    }
    public Person(Person original) {

        this.name = original.name;
        this.username = original.username;
        this.password = original.password;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", username="
                + username + ", password=" + password +"]";
    }

}
```

Admin

```
public class Admin extends Person  {

    private double salary;


public Administrator() {
    this.name = "";
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.salary= 0;

}
public Admin(String name, String username, String password, double salary) {

    this.name = name;   
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.salary = salary;

}
public Admin(Admin original) {
    super(original);
    this.name = original.name;
    this.username = original.username;
    this.salary = original.salary;
    this.salary = original.salary;
}


public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(double salary) {
    salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Administrator [salary=" + salary + "]";
}
```

}

DAO for creating new admin:

```
    public static int createAdmin(Admin d) {
    int status = 0;
    con = SQLite.dbConnector();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into admin values(?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, d.getName());
        ps.setString(2, d.getUsername());
        ps.setString(3, d.getPassword());
        ps.setString(4, d.getSalary());
        int rs = ps.executeUpdate();

    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return status;
}
```

on DAO i'm using SQLite to insert data in database, other object that in need to create like Book are working with this pattern

partsGUI for inserting data:

```
    nameAdmin = new JTextField();
    nameAdmin.setColumns(10);
    korisnickoAdministratora.setBounds(625, 249, 114, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(nameAdmin);

    usernameAdmin = new JTextField();
    usernameAdmin.setColumns(10);
    usernameAdmin.setBounds(625, 312, 114, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(usernameAdmin);

    passwordAdmin = new JTextField();
    passwordAdmin.setColumns(10);
    passwordAdmin.setBounds(625, 279, 114, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(passwordAdmin);

    salaryAdmin = new JTextField();
    salaryAdmin.setColumns(10);
    salaryAdmin.setBounds(625, 344, 114, 21);
    frame.getContentPane().add(salaryAdministratora);
```

and part that connects gui with dao:

```
    JButton btnAddAdmin = new JButton("AddAdmin");
    btnAddAdmin.setBounds(545, 391, 192, 27);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddAdmin);
    btnAddAdmin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {

                double s = Double.parseDouble(salaryAdmin.getText());

                Admin d = new Admin(nameAdmin.getText(),usernameAdmin.getText(),passwordAdmin.getText(),s);
                System.out.println(d);
                AdminDAO.createAdmin(d);
                System.out.println(d);

            }catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
            );
```

now the problem is that this make new admin with just salary parameter and System.out.prinln(d) print just this:

```
Admin [salary=123.0]
```

Comment: You have overridden the `toString` and don't call super or aren't including the other parameters. So obviously those won't be printed to the console.

Comment: Do a call to the parent constructor using `super(name, username, password);` and then do `this.salary = salary;` in you `Admin` class. Also in the `Person` class you have an `Osoba` named constructor which is wrong and needs to be removed.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex yes, fix it and it works :)

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, i have been struggling with this for some time now, it worked :)

Comment: @MilošĆurčić Imma turn this into an answer.

Comment: @MilošĆurčić you can go ahead up-vote and make this the accepted answer in case you feel it helped you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Admin` constructors are not performing a correct call to the parent constructor. Instead of doing:

```
public Administrator() {
    this.name = "";
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.salary= 0;

}
public Admin(String name, String username, String password, double salary) {
    this.name = name;   
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  this.salary = salary;

}
public Admin(Admin original) {
    super(original);
    this.name = original.name;
    this.username = original.username;
    this.salary = original.salary;
    this.salary = original.salary;
}


// person

 public Person() {
    this.name = "";
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";
}

public Osoba( String name, String username, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public Person(Person original) {
    this.name = original.name;
    this.username = original.username;
    this.password = original.password;
}
```

You should do something like this:

```
public Adminstrator() {
    super();
    this.salary = 0;
}

public Administrator(String name, String username, String password, double salary) {
    super(name, username, password);
    this.salary = salary;
}

public Adminstrator(Administrator original) {
    super(original);
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Also this bit a code is wrong and should be removed:

```
public Osoba( String name, String username, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Finally I suggest you have a good read regarding inheritance.